# jax-rs @Provider doesn't pick up correctly when jax-rs runs as Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jax-rs

I have JAX-RS integrated with the Spring Boot app.

I want to use LocalDate as a query parameter.

The example of endpoint is below:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("book/publication/year")
override fun findInRange(
    @QueryParam("from") fromDate: LocalDate?,
    @QueryParam("to") toDate: LocalDate?
): Response
```

If I use String everything works fine, so the issue with LocalDate type itself.

I found an article from Sebastian Daschner: https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/jaxrs-convert-params

I have now these classes:

LocalDateConverter.kt:

```
class LocalDateConverter : ParamConverter<LocalDate?> {
    override fun fromString(value: String?): LocalDate? {
        return if (value == null) null else LocalDate.parse(value)
    }

    override fun toString(value: LocalDate?): String? {
        return value?.toString()
    }
}
```

LocalDateParamConverterProvider.kt:

```
@Provider
public class LocalDateParamConverterProvider : ParamConverterProvider {
    override fun <T> getConverter(
        rawType: Class<T>,
        genericType: Type,
        annotations: Array<Annotation>
    ): ParamConverter<T>? {
        return if (rawType == LocalDate::class.java) LocalDateConverter() as ParamConverter<T> else null
    }
}
```

Nothing has changed. The question is how to make Spring Boot pick up custom ParameterConverterProvider when run in Spring Boot?

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to annotate it with @JsonFormat? Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have Spring Boot + JAX-RS integrated, I need to register for all the JAX-RS classes in `ResourceConfig` or classes inherited from it.

```
register(LocalDateParamConverterProvider::class.java)
```

This article helped a lot to find it out: https://dzone.com/articles/using-jax-rs-with-spring-boot-instead-of-mvc